# When can a metric space be embedded in the plane?

Tags: metric-spaces

It's easy to check if a graph can be embedded in the plane: just check for forbidden minors. Is it also easy to check if a "distance function" can be embedded?
Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions one can check?

I know there's a lot of research into approximate embeddings, but clearly in some cases that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following

*Conjecture.* A metric space $(X,d)$ can be isometrically embedded in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ endowed with the standard metric $\rho$ iff each four-point subspace of $(X,d)$ can be isometrically embedded in the plane.

To build such an embedding $i$ we fix three different points $x$, $y$ and $z$ of $X$ for which the triangle inequality is strict and fix an arbitrary embedding $i_0:(\{x,y,z\},d|\{x,y,z\})\to (\mathbb R^2, \rho )$ (case when there are no such triple $\{x,y,z\}$ have to be considered separately). Let $t\in X$ be an arbitrary point. It seems that there exists an unique point $t’\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $d(x,t)=\rho(i_0(x),t’)$, $d(y,t)=\rho(i_0(y),t’)$, and $d(z,t)=\rho(i_0(z),t’)$. Put $i(t)=t’$. Then it seems that $i$ is an isometric embedding.

Comment: Yeah, I guess as long as we have three points, we can make a triangle, and then build out the the rest of the embedding from that. If too many points lie on the same line, we might have to use some backtracking.

Comment: @ThomasAhle [My conjecture is almost correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557030/how-many-dimensions-we-need-to-represent-weighted-graph-in-metric-space/3562724#comment7326766_3562724).

Answer (score 4):

There are very high obstacles to isometric embedding a metric space in the plane! If there exist three paints $a,b,c$ where the triangle  inequality is strict (i.e. $d(a,b)+d(b,c)+d(a,c)<2\max\{d(a,b),d(b,c),d(a,c)\}$) then any other point is "very likely" to produce a contradiction: From knowing $d(a,x)$ and $d(b,x)$ there are only two candidate positions for $x$ and it really needs a "coincidence" if one of them has the correct distance from $c$.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem likely to happen out of coincidence :) But it seems like there might be an efficient algorithm for checking if a distance function comes from a plane.