# Feasibility of constructing a geometric figure of $n$ vertices with given distances $d_{ij}$ between vertices $i$ and $j$?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, metric-spaces

I know I can construct a triangle with sides $(3,4,5)$. I also know that I cannot construct the triangle with sides (3,4,8), because the third side is longer than the sum of the two other.

> Now let's say, I want to construct a geometrical figure with $n$ vertices with a given distance $d_{ij}$ between them vertices $i$ and $j$ (this geometrical figure could be described by a graph).
>
> Is there a way to prove that this is or not possible to construct such a figure?

Is there an area in graph theory that is applied to determine the feasibility of a geometrical construction?

Comment: Wikipedia's ["geometric graph theory" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory) may give you a place to start.

Comment: If the size of the largest segment is greater than the sum of all the rest, than you can not construct a polygon. In all other cases you can and many of them for each set.

Comment: Imagine that I want to add a vertice to the (3,4,5) triangle so that it is a distance 1 from 2 of the vertices. This is not possible and the largest segment is not greater than the sum of the rest. I don't know if this is out of the definition of a polygon, but am looking for a more general answer.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557030/how-many-dimensions-we-need-to-represent-weighted-graph-in-metric-space) thread answers your question.